# POI read excel celltype error No such property: CellType for class

Tags: apache-poi, katalon-studio

I have created a groovy keyword script (in Katalon) to make use of the POI XSSF to read the excel file.

but hitting an error "No such property: CellType for class: excel.readexcel" when running the test case.

I'm not sure if that is the POI library issue or I'm using the wrong syntax?

this is groovy

```html
package excel
import java.io.IOException

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import com.kms.katalon.core.annotation.Keyword



public class readexcel {


 @Keyword

 def post(String name) throws IOException{

  try {

   //FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE_NAME));
   FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\JY\\testmatrix.xlsx");
   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
   Sheet datatypeSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
   Iterator<Row> iterator = datatypeSheet.iterator();

   while (iterator.hasNext()) {

    Row currentRow = iterator.next();
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = currentRow.iterator();

    while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

     Cell currentCell = cellIterator.next();
     //getCellTypeEnum shown as deprecated for version 3.15
     //getCellTypeEnum ill be renamed to getCellType starting from version 4.0
     if (currentCell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
      System.out.print(currentCell.getStringCellValue() + "--");
     } else if (currentCell.getCellType() == CellType.NUMERIC) {
      System.out.print(currentCell.getNumericCellValue() + "--");
     }

    }
    System.out.println();

   }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }

 }
}
```

this is test case to call the keyword and print the result to check if the reading successful or not.

```html
import static com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.CheckpointFactory.findCheckpoint
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestDataFactory.findTestData
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.checkpoint.Checkpoint as Checkpoint
import com.kms.katalon.core.cucumber.keyword.CucumberBuiltinKeywords as CucumberKW
import com.kms.katalon.core.mobile.keyword.MobileBuiltInKeywords as Mobile
import com.kms.katalon.core.model.FailureHandling as FailureHandling
import com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCase as TestCase
import com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.TestData as TestData
import com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.TestObject as TestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS
import com.kms.katalon.core.webui.keyword.WebUiBuiltInKeywords as WebUI
import internal.GlobalVariable as GlobalVariable

def result = CustomKeywords.'excel.readexcel.post'('')

println(result)
```

error

```html
2020-02-04 15:15:14.758 DEBUG testcase.try                             - 1: result = excel.readexcel.post("")
Version--Description--Date--
1.0--Test matrix for collection of test data and summary of test cases for Drug Service.--2020-02-04 15:15:16.044 ERROR k.k.c.m.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass - ❌ No such property: CellType for class: excel.readexcel
2020-02-04 15:15:16.046 ERROR c.k.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor   - ❌ Test Cases/try FAILED.
Reason:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: CellType for class: excel.readexcel
 at excel.readexcel.post(readexcel.groovy:42)
 at excel.readexcel.invokeMethod(readexcel.groovy)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.invokeStaticMethod(CustomKeywordDelegatingMetaClass.java:50)
 at try.run(try:16)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.run(ScriptEngine.java:194)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.ScriptEngine.runScriptAsRawText(ScriptEngine.java:119)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.runScript(TestCaseExecutor.java:337)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.doExecute(TestCaseExecutor.java:328)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.processExecutionPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:307)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.accessMainPhase(TestCaseExecutor.java:299)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.execute(TestCaseExecutor.java:233)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:114)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
 at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
 at TempTestCase1580800511604.run(TempTestCase1580800511604.groovy:21)
```

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you using?

Comment: @Gagravarr I'm using POI 3.9.0

Comment: You need to upgrade then! [That version is over 7 years old!](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.9)

Comment: that is what Katalon currently supported...i cannot upgrade them. @Gagravarr

Comment: Then you need to follow documentation and tutorials for that version, you can't follow docs for the latest version using the latest class names on 7 year old code... Docs ship in the binary release package, grab that for your ancient version

Comment: i have done the codes. this thread is resolved. thanks!